# Get arrays value Multipart/form-data with language

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms

Multipart/form-data with arrays ----------//---------------------

I can not get value "fields.c".

```
*---------------html form
<form action="/companyInfo" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name='txtCompanyPhone' value='0909 234 456' />
<input type="text" name='txtCompanyName[vi]' value='Namevi' />
<input type="text" name='txtCompanyName[en]' value='Nameen' />
<input type="text" name='txtCompanyName[ja]' value='Nameja' />
</form>

*---------------controller "companyInfo"
var form = new multiparty.Form();
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        console.log(fields);
        //result
        // txtCompanyPhone: ['0909 234 456'],
        // ,'txtCompanyName[vi]': ['Namevi'],
        // ,'txtCompanyName[en]': ['Nameen'],
        // ,'txtCompanyName[ja]': ['Nameja'],

        console.log(fields.txtCompanyPhone);
        result------ ['0909 234 456']

        console.log(fields.txtCompanyName[vi]);
        //result ----- error

        var c = 'txtCompanyName[vi]';
        console.log(fields.c);
        //result ------undefined

        //----------Help me show results-----------------            
}
```

How to get value "fields.c" or "fields.txtCompanyName[vi]" in this form?

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/pillarjs/multiparty/issues/81

Answer (score 1):

Try `fields['txtCompanyName']['vi']`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `fields['txtCompanyName[vi]']`